# Cambie mi sistema escrito en php de un servidor normal de Hostinger a un VPS de Hostinger y el sistema no funciona

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, hosting, vps

tengo el siguiente problema, ayer cambie de servidor compartido a un VPS del proveedor Hostinger, y ahora no funciona el sistema, y además de eso algunas palabras que llevan acento salen con el siguiente signo � y eso que tengo puesto bien el UTF-8, el VPS tiene la misma versión de PHP que tengo yo en mi servidor local y en el servidor compartido de Hostinger, entonces no se identificar el problema.
El sistema tiene una opción con la cual se abre un cliente y muestra su información en un modal a través de Ajax, funciona bien en el servidor compartido de hostinger y en el servidor local, pero en el VPS no muestra los datos, sale todo en blanco.
[image: Así se ve funcionando, en el servidor local y en el compartido]

[image: Así se ve en el VPS]

Ahora la verdad no entiendo que paso, porque el sistema tenía más de 5 meses en uso y todo bien, cambiamos a un VPS y ahora nada, esta todo bug, no sé qué otra información puedo facilitar para que me puedan ayudar con la solución. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: ¿esa información la sacas de una base de datos?  ¿has comprobado el tipo de conexión que tiene?  quizas lo que ves es el resultado de una extración de datos de la base de datos con una codificación distinta a la que tenias en los otros sitios

Comment: Si Amigo, esa información viene desde una base de datos, como puedo ver la codificación de la que hablas?

Comment: Pues en /etc/my.cnf deberías tener estas líneas: `[mysql] default-character-set=utf8` (son dos lineas, o busca el [mysql] si existe y lo pones debajo y reinicias el servidor mysql)

Comment: ¿y bien?  ¿has podido hacer **todos** los cambios de mi respuesta?  usas mysql o mariadb? ¿que version?

Comment: Aun no encuentro en que parte puedo editar el archivo my.cnf este vps es raro, cuando lo encuentre lo hago y te comento.

Comment: normalmente se edita mediante SSH y lo encontrarás en la carpeta /etc/, y el archivo se llama my.cnf (eso si tu vps es linux tipo centos)

Comment: Tengo el acceso SSH pero pongo todos los datos bien y solo me dice que no se pudo conectar al servidor

Comment: eso ya... es decir, puede ser por muchos motivos, un firewall que cierra el puerto, un intento de entrar como **root** lo cual cada vez se permite menos y debes entrar con un usuario normal y luego hacer el **su** para convertirte en root, no se, hay varias cosas que pueden estar impidientelo.  En el panel de control de hostinger no tienen una consola web para acceder a tu VPS mediante terminal?  con eso ya bastaria para entrar

Comment: Cuando contratas un VPS es porque sabes administrar un servidor, porque en caso contrario vas a sufrir y mucho, pues te van a pasar muchas cosas que vas a tener que arreglar via SSH para afinarlo.

Comment: A menos que sea un VPS gestionado, ante lo cual debes pedirle a tu proveedor que te haga esos cambios

Comment: Estoy en eso, soy nuevo estoy aprendiendo a gestionar VPS el detalle que Hostinger tiene una interfaz que para mi es confusa

Comment: Bueno, supongo que tendran manuales o ayudas que puedan servirte de referencia.  Pues nada, cuando consigas entrar y hacer esos cambios espero que te funcionen. Suerte! :-)

Comment: Listo amigo hice lo que me dijiste y funciono, muchas gracias

Comment: Perfecto! Me alegro :-)  Saludos!

Comment: Oye ahora tengo otro problema, es que ahora no guarda datos en la base de datos.

Comment: ops... y eso?  algun error que veas en alguna parte?  algo que permita deducir que sucede?

Comment: No se, puedo agregar datos pero no me permite editar registros, osea actualizar puede ser error del VPS?, o el código?, por que como comente antes y sabes todo funcionaba y funciona aun bien el local y en el servidor de hostinger

Comment: si te deja agregar pero no actualizar entonces será un problema del código seguramente... ponlo en una pregunta para que te lo revisen a ver

Comment: Aunque ahora que recuerdo, a mi también me pasó algo raro y tuve que cambiar una linea y poner esto en su lugar: `sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`  (originalmente habia todo un churro de opciones)

Comment: (Eso en el /etc/my.cnf, claro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al ser un VPS comprueba si tienes estos valores en el archivo **/etc/my.cnf** (esto para MySQL, no para MariaDB):

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8
```

y si no los tienes agrégalos y reinicia el servicio MySQL y prueba de nuevo.